# OIM EBS Connector Upgrade

Tags: oracle, connector, oracle-ebs, oim, identity-management

I am upgrading Oracle EBS (e-Business Suite) connector for OIM (Oracle Identity Manager)

I am going through this case that when I upgrade the EBS connector, I am loosing the previous customizations. For example:

1. Custom process forms are not getting migrated from older version to newer version. Meaning, custom tasks from process form are getting lost and no more visible
2. Custom reconciliation rules are not getting migrated from older version to newer version. Meaning, custom reconciliation rules are getting lost and no more visible

My question in this regard is:

1. Did any one who performed similar upgrade faced this issue ?
2. If similar issue is faced then what is the solution to this ? or what other approach we can take to migrate all old process forms, recon rule etc
3. Can someone suggest if upgrade of EBS connector for OIM is possible at all or clean install is better option (this is the least preferred for us)

Comment: Never worked with EBS, but it's sorta expected, as newer version would deploy a replacement for the existing form/resource/process. Does connector documentation have any chapter, describing the process of upgrade? If not, then maybe try to open an SR with Support?

Comment: thanks @PhilippGrigoryev atleast this information like its expected is slightly helpful. Documentation is there but the document is using ambiguous words like "may be, may not be migrated", "might be or might not be migrated" which is not very helpful for me.

Comment: Totally share your frustration with fuzzy documentation. Based on my experience of upgrading other connectors, I can recommend to do an export of the existing one and then use XML to re-introduce some pieces of your customizations back. Far from ideal scenario, but without an SR it'll be hard to understand, if there is any other way of preserving your configuration